# How can I know the inventory history for each product?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I know the inventory history for each product? know the date each time the stock was modified

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide clarify your question and provide an example of your code? It will lead to more views and faster answers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately WooCommerce doesn't store any kind of audit log or history record on products inventory.

You can find this thread on  WC support forum: [Inventory history on WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/inventory-history-on-woocommerce/)

According to [this article](https://www.pluginever.com/best-inventory-management-plugins-woocommerce/), [Veeqo for Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/veeqo-for-woocommerce/) has a feature to store inventory history, however I'm not sure if it can help you with what you want.